# Refactoring Javascript into pure functions to make code more readable and maintainable

Tags: javascript

Note:

1. I am very new to Javascript.
2. The code I provided is long but not complicated.

The code below works and runs fine.  But I would like to seperate it out into logical 'pure' functions to make it clearer whats going on.
I started to re-factor this myself and made some good progress, however, I quickly started to return to problems with dependencies and embedded functions.

I'd be interested to see how others would write the following:

```
   var contactsController = {

fetch: function()
{
    // Parses the returned JSON into the database
    var fetchSuccess = function(json)
    {          
        var NAME = "Contact",
            COLUMNS = ['Name', 'GivenNames', 'FamilyName', 'Telephone'];

        if (json.Response.Code == 0)
        {
            database.open();
            database.dropTable(NAME);
            database.createTable(NAME, COLUMNS);    

            // .Contact is an array of contact objects
            var contacts = json.Contacts.Contact; 

            for (var contact in contacts)
            {
                var contact = contacts[contact];
                database.insert(NAME, COLUMNS, [contact.Name, contact.GivenNames, contact.FamilyName, contact.Telephone] );
            }

            contactsController.populateList();
        }
    }

    ServerConn.fetchContacts(fetchSuccess);
},

populateList: function()
{
    var $page = $("#contactsPage");

    $page.find(".content").empty();
    $page.find(".content").html("<ul data-role='listview' data-filter='true'><\/ul>");
    $list = $page.find(".content ul");

    var render = function(character)
    {
        return function(tx, result)
        {
            var max = result.rows.length;

            if (max > 0)
            {
                var header = "<li data-role='list-divider'>" + character + "</li>",
                    listItem = $(header);

                $list.append(header);

                for (var i = 0; i < result.rows.length; i++) 
                {
                    var contact = result.rows.item(i),
                        strHtml = "<li><a href='#contactPage'>" + contact.Name + "<\/a><\/li>";

                    listItem = $(strHtml);
                    $list.append(listItem);

                    // store the data in the DOM
                    $list.find("a:last").data("contactObj", contact);
                }

                $list.find("a").click(function()
                {
                    var $this = $(this);
                    $("#contactPage").data("contactObj", $this.data("contactObj"));
                });

                $list.listview(); //Only fires once?
                $list.listview('refresh');  
            }
        }
    }

    var str = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    for(var i = 0; i < str.length; i++)
    {
        var sql = "SELECT * FROM Contact WHERE Exclude = ? AND Name LIKE ? ORDER BY Name",
            nextChar = str.charAt(i),
            selargs =  ['0', nextChar + "%"];

        database.open();
        database.query(sql, selargs, render(nextChar));
    }
}
```

};

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A lot of the logic in your code belongs to a template, not directly in code.
You can find tons of templating engines for javascript or make your own.

An example of a template that could be used here is:

```
<script type="text/html" id="letter-index-view">
@if( model.result.rows.length ) {
    <li data-role="list-divider">@model.result.character</li>
    @foreach( contact in model.result.rows ) {
        <li><a href="#contactPage" id="@contact.ContactID">@contact.Name</a></li>
    }
}
</script>
```

Now `populateList` becomes this:

```
populateList: function()
    {
        var $page = $("#contactsPage"),
            tmpl = Template.getById("letter-index-view"),
            str = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";

        $list = $("<ul>", {
            "data-role": "listview",
            "data-filter": "true"
        });

        $list.on( "click", "a", function() {
            $("#contactPage").data("contactId", this.id);
        });

        $page.find(".content").empty().append( $list );

        for(var i = 0; i < str.length; i++)
        {
            var nextChar = str.charAt(i),
                sql = "SELECT *, ? AS character FROM Contact WHERE Exclude = ? AND Name LIKE ? ORDER BY Name",
                selargs =  [nextChar, '0', nextChar + "%"];

            database.open();
            database.query(sql, selargs, function(tx, result){
                $list.append( tmpl( {
                    result: result
                }));

                $list.listview(); //Only fires once?
                $list.listview('refresh');  
            });
        }
    }
```

Note that I made some other changes as well, since template is kind of static html it cannot have object references like
`$list.find("a:last").data("contactObj", contact);` so the links are uniquely identified with their database row id.

I also modified the query to return the character used in that query so a static function
can be used for the query callback instead of 26 different ones.

Another reason for `populateList` being lengthy is that it's doing view and model stuff at the same time. You should move
all the DOM stuff into a view.

Comment: There are some really nice bits of code here.  I particularly like storing the character in the SQL rather than using the immediately returning function.   Is the template from scratch or have you used a framework?

Comment: @CrimsonChin Not sure what you mean... I just wrote the template according to your code. A template engine would convert that to real javascript function (`Template.getById("letter-index-view")`) which can be called to generate HTML according to the templating language used.